# Current Location Background service is not working

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I need to get Current Location from my Service class & pass the recently get values to the activity class.But using, this class I can not get Current location's lattitude & longitude. Here is my code.Please check it.

**Service Class:**

```
public class MyLocation extends Service {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    Context con;
    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {
        con = context;
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult = result;
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return network_enabled;
            }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(con, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (network_enabled)
                net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if (net_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? onLocationChanged is not called at all? Or it is called and you can't pass the results to activity? Or something else? Also, consider using Google Play Services API for location services - it is recommended to use by Android developer site.

Comment: onLocationChanged is not called.

Comment: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork); - You don't even check here if network provider is enabled. You check it view lines above but you don't do anything with the result. Also, I don't think onLocationChanged will ever be called if you have no permissions - so checking permissions inside onLocationChanged is pointless (I might be wrong though).

Comment: in case of GPS_PROVIDER, you will get location or onLocationChanged will call only when you are moving .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get current location lat lng using this GPSTracker.java

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;// flag for GPS status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;// flag for network status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;// flag for GPS status
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    /* How many GeoCoder should return our GPSTracker */
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    /* The minimum distance to change Updates in meters */
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    /* The minimum time between updates in milliseconds */
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    /* Declaring a Location Manager */
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            /* getting GPS status */
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            /* getting network status */
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                /* no network provider is enabled */
                //gpsEnableAlertDialog();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                /* First get location from Network Provider */
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* if GPS Enabled get LAT,LNG using GPS Services */
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * application
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/WiFi enabled
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * launch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        /* Setting Dialog Title */
        //alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        /* Setting Dialog Message */
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Enable it?");

        /* On pressing Settings button */
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /* on pressing cancel button */
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        /* Showing Alert Message */
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    /*
     * Close project which is open 
     * this sialog is used to disable all menu item
     */
    private void gpsEnableAlertDialog() {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.dialog_close_project, null);

        final NiftyDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(mContext);
        dialogBuilder.isCancelableOnTouchOutside(true).withDuration(700).withEffect(Effectstype.Shake).setCustomView(view,mContext).show();

        TextView edt_searchitem_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_searchitem_item);
        edt_searchitem_item.setText("GPS is disabled in your device. Enable it?");
        /*
         * Close project and disable all menu item
         */
        Button btn_closePrj_yes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_closePrj_yes);
        btn_closePrj_yes.setText("Enable GPS");
        btn_closePrj_yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialogBuilder.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity)mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_layout,R.anim.left_to_right_layout);
            }
        });


        /*
         * return same as previouse state
         */
        Button btn_close_prj_no = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_prj_no);
        btn_close_prj_no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialogBuilder.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    /* Extra(Below method not use in application) */

    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * 
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
        if (location != null) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                /**
                 * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses that
                 * are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the
                 * given latitude and longitude.
                 */
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

                return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error Msg:", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * 
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     * 
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     * 
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     * 
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download project from here ([Get Current Location Using Background Service](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/service-in-android/))

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:text="Location using service"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:orientation="vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Longitude"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Area"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/tv_area"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Locality"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/tv_locality"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:text="Get Location"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.renderscript.Double2;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn_start;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    boolean boolean_permission;
    TextView tv_latitude, tv_longitude, tv_address,tv_area,tv_locality;
    SharedPreferences mPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor medit;
    Double latitude,longitude;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        tv_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        tv_latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
        tv_longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
        tv_area = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_area);
        tv_locality = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_locality);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        medit = mPref.edit();


        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (boolean_permission) {

                    if (mPref.getString("service", "").matches("")) {
                        medit.putString("service", "service").commit();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
                        startService(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable the gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        fn_permission();
    }

    private void fn_permission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) {


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

                        },
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }
        } else {
            boolean_permission = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    boolean_permission = true;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            latitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latutide"));
            longitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longitude"));

            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

                tv_area.setText(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                tv_locality.setText(stateName);
                tv_address.setText(countryName);



            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            tv_latitude.setText(latitude+"");
            tv_longitude.setText(longitude+"");
            tv_address.getText();


        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }


}
```

**GoogleService.java**

```
package servicetutorial.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by deepshikha on 24/11/16.
 */

public class GoogleService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    boolean isGPSEnable = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
    double latitude,longitude;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    long notify_interval = 1000;
    public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
    Intent intent;




    public GoogleService() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(),5,notify_interval);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
//        fn_getlocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    private void fn_getlocation(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){

        }else {

            if (isNetworkEnable){
                location = null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
                if (locationManager!=null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location!=null){

                        Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                        Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }

            }


            if (isGPSEnable){
                location = null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
                if (locationManager!=null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location!=null){
                        Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                        Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }

    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fn_getlocation();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fn_update(Location location){

        intent.putExtra("latutide",location.getLatitude()+"");
        intent.putExtra("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }


}
```